# Change Grid Size of Home Page without rooting phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Is it possible to change the grid size of the home page using Jelly Bean 4.2.2 without rooting phone ?

Comment: What grid? The desktop? The app drawer? Something else? You've also tagged this with two different phones (S3 and S4) - which are you asking about, or are you asking about both?

Comment: Both phones. I am talking about the desktop\homepage @eldarerathis

Comment: Try a launcher which supports that, e.g. [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher).

Comment: @Izzy Interesting app, is this the only way to do this ?

Comment: @Izzy - I remembered Apex Launcher, too. I am also still querying for a foldering app I remember that let you minimize icons down to about 8 across, letting you have about 20-30 on a homepage.

Comment: @wbogacz the launcher is actually interesting, but it's a hassle. I would rather keep the interface that came with S4 rather than force this Apex launcher theme ( which I'm assuming is the original android theme ? ).

Comment: @wbogacz yes, I remember there was a widget combining 4-in-1, about 2 years ago. I never cared, so I forgot about that one. I also doubt that's what EnDroid is after. // EnDroid: Apex was just an example. There are others as well :)

Comment: @Izzy Is this possible only through launchers ?

Comment: Guess what your homescreen is (hint: you can launch things from there). As far as I know, there are two possibilities: Either the launcher, or multi-widgets. I never heard of anything else, even with increasing density. If you'd count that as an answer, I'd compile one :)

Comment: @Izzy I think you should add that as an answer. I'll also wait before accepting as maybe others know some other method. But you should definitely add that as an answer :)

Comment: Did so. Even found a 2rd way while searching for the multi-widget -- I almost forgot about Zoom :)

Comment: @EnDroid Please take a look at the update to my answer below -- that might make you keel over! I don't believe there can be anything out there giving you more freedom in homescreen customization!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways known to me how this could be achieved:

#### Using a launcher which supports this

There are several launchers available on Google Play which let you configure the grid size of your homescreen as well as of your app drawer. One of those is [Apex Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher), which I use myself. Another example is [GO Launcher EX](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex), which I run on another device. I'm pretty sure a load of other launchers does this as well.

**EDIT:** Holy whatever. If that's not enough, take a look at [Lighning Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.pierrox.lightning_launcher). Grid size? What grid? Who needs a grid? Icon size, font size, orientation -- feel free to ***design*** your own homescreen! And now, for the size of the package. Sitting? 200 kB (still looking for the hook), working with Android 1.6 and up. Truly AMAZING!

Ah, and what comes below: Multi-whatever is already included. Widgets in folders? No problem, either... Well, that bunch of features must need permis... what? Only USB-Storage? Can't believe... I just sent it to one of my devices to take a closer look :)

#### Using "Multi-Widgets"

There are some sort of "widget expanders" out there, which pick 4 (or more) widgets and combine them into one "compressed widget". One example for this group is [Multicon Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.h9kdroid.multicon).

#### Zoom

And then there's [Zoom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.zoom), from the dev of [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (with which it even integrates). According to its description, this also should be an option:

> Unique on any computer: design your own homescreen widgets to do whatever you like!
>
> Position, size and overlay elements in the drag-and-drop editor. Two views: full-zoom for easier editing, actual-size for previewing.

Comment: Multicon Widget - That's the one I was remembering!

Comment: There must be another one as well (unless it has been taken away from playstore). I remember two of that kind. Btw, for a really crazy launcher variant: [TSF Launcher Ubuntu Style](http://phandroid.com/2013/01/17/ubuntu-android-theme/). Not that I'd use it (or even buy it for > 12 EUR), but it's a completely adjustable thingy :)

Comment: @wbogacz take a look at my update, what crazy stuff I just discovered. Guess that's something I've got to play with the next couple of days...

Comment: I'm still freaking. Just pushed it to one of my devices. If I'm without a job next week, you know the cause #D